# Cannot write pin LOW

Tags: programming, pins, digital

All the other examples I've seen have had coding errors where they set a pin LOW in a loop with no delay so that it goes high again right away - but this problem is different, and probably something obvious.

I set up a breadboard memory (EEPROM or similarly-pinned flash) programmer ([ala BenEater and many similar sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K88pgWhEb1M&t=1939s)) using two 74**595s for the first 15 address bits as well as the OE# bit in the MSB spot, and the nano digital outputs for the 8 data bits as well as the WE# (write-enable) bit.  The data, address, and OE# pins set correctly every time.  The WE# pin, however, stays HIGH forever once it goes HIGH.

I have tried every digital pin for WE#, I have tried every analog pin with an analogWrite.  I have tried now three different memory chips and three Arduino Nanos that I've used successfully elsewhere, but still no success.

The only thing I can assume is that the WE# pin on the memory ICs somehow is keeping the line high, but I can't for the life of me figure out how that's possible.

Code and logic analyzer example:

```
/*
 EEPROM Programmer 
 In this case, programming a SST39SF010A
 55ns read access, 22us write time
 Software Data Protection to write:
 (0x5555, 0xAA)
 (0x2AAA, 0x55)
 (0x5555, 0xA0)
 */

#define SHIFT_DATA  13
#define SHIFT_CLK   12
#define SHIFT_LATCH 11
#define ROM_D0      2
#define ROM_D1      3
#define ROM_D2      4
#define ROM_D3      5
#define ROM_D4      6
#define ROM_D5      7
#define ROM_D6      8
#define ROM_D7      9
#define WRITE_EN    10

void setAddress(int address, bool outputEnable) {
  shiftOut(SHIFT_DATA, SHIFT_CLK, MSBFIRST, ((address >> 8) | (outputEnable ? 0x00 : 0x80))); // High bits
  shiftOut(SHIFT_DATA, SHIFT_CLK, MSBFIRST, address); // Low bits
  digitalWrite(SHIFT_LATCH, LOW);
  digitalWrite(SHIFT_LATCH, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(SHIFT_LATCH, LOW);
}

byte readROM(int address) {
  for (int pin = ROM_D0; pin <= ROM_D7; pin++) {
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
  }
  byte data = 0;
  setAddress(address, /* outputEnable */ true);
  // Read each pin
  for (int pin = ROM_D7; pin >= ROM_D0; pin--) {
    data = (data << 1) + digitalRead(pin);
  }
  return data;
}

void printContents() {
  for (int base = 0; base < 256; base += 16) {
    byte data[16];
    char buf[80];
    for (int offset = 0; offset < 16; offset++) {
      data[offset] = readROM(base + offset);
    }
    // buffer (string) to hold the formatted data
    sprintf(buf, "%03x:  %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x  %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x",
      base, data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7],
      data[8], data[9], data[10], data[11], data[12], data[13], data[14], data[15]);
    Serial.println(buf);
  }
}

void writeROM(int address, byte data) {
  for (int pin = ROM_D0; pin <= ROM_D7; pin++) {
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  }
  setAddress(address, /* outputEnable */ false);
  for (int pin = ROM_D0; pin <= ROM_D7; pin++) {
    digitalWrite(pin, (data & 0x01));
    data = (data >> 1);
  }
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  delay(1);
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(56700);
  Serial.flush();

  pinMode(SHIFT_DATA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHIFT_CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SHIFT_LATCH, OUTPUT);

  // Set pull-up resistor
  digitalWrite(WRITE_EN, HIGH);
  pinMode(WRITE_EN, OUTPUT);

  Serial.println();

  writeROM(0x5555, 0xAA);
  writeROM(0x2AAA, 0x55);
  writeROM(0x5555, 0xA0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    writeROM(i, i % 13);
  }
  printContents();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

[image: Logic Analyzer output]

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=68753.0

Comment: @MichaelT I am not seeing how that link is equivalent.  The pin in my project is not left floating.  It is connected and does not respond to commands to set to LOW.

Comment: Does the pin go low when disconnected from the memory chip?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Good question - when it isn't connected, it stays low.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Well, sometimes it just takes one rational question, thank you.  Somehow it works on my Arduino Uno but none of my Nanos...  I will just keep going from here and try to trouble shoot the nanos later

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a case of both chips trying driving the OE line (in opposite directions), destroying the output driver? What is the voltage of WE# on the memchip without the pin being disconnected? Is floating? Can you manually ground the pin and see a 0V on the multimeter? Maybe also see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/107190/158783

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Ding ding.  Not sure how, but somehow OE and WE are shorted on my breadboard.  It was the common factor, the memory have the same pinouts so I just swapped them.  Everything was driving the same channels high, thus no way to bring it low.  Also I think it killed my Uno D10 pin... :-(  But thanks for the help - I wasn't even thinking of that and I have no idea how two channels so far apart on a breadboard are shorted together, but my DMM reads 0.01 Ohms between them.  Now it's time to break apart a breadboard...